# Matching enclosing characters Python

Tags: python-2.7

So I am trying to split characters a certain way.
If I provide this string:

text (text (adsf (asdfasdfjkl) asdfjlkasdjf) stuff) (morestuff stuff)

I want it to split it into:

['text', '(text (adsf (asdfasdfjkl) asdfjlkasdjf) stuff)', '(morestuff stuff)']

Code I had:

```
def pair_char(left, right, start, text, exclusive=False, verbose=False):
    package = []
    for e, c in enumerate(text):
        left_c = right_c = 0
        if text[e] == left:
            left_c += 1
            marker = start = e
            while text[marker+1] != right or left_c > right_c:
                marker += 1
                if verbose:
                    print left_c, right_c, text[marker], left, right, text[marker]==left, text[marker]==right
                if marker+1 >= len(text):
                    break
                if text[marker] == left_c:
                    print "left_c"
                    left_c += 1
                if text[marker] == right_c:
                    print "right_c"
                    right_c += 1
            end = marker
            if exclusive:
                package.append(text[start+1:end])
            else:
                package.append(text[start:end+1])
            e = end
    package = "".join(package)
    return package
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you written any code for this?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work correctly, it splits the same sequence multiple times. For example: instead of "(adsf (asdfasdfjkl) asdfjlkasdfj) stff)" it would output "(adsf (asdfasdfjkl) asdfjlkasdfj) stff)", "(asdfasdfjkl)", etc. @khuderm

Comment: So you want division of parenthesized expressions on the same level?

Comment: it would be better to include whatever you tried in your question and there will be plenty of people to help you out. otherwise people look at it as someone looking to get their work done by someone else. that is most likely why someone downvoted.

Comment: Alright, I updated it @khuderm.